# How do I interact with a program that requires clicking on its system tray icon if my GUI doesn't have a dynamic system tray?

Tags: linux, software-installation, gui

In the installation process for Talon, I need to install the Conformer voice engine by right-clicking the Talon system tray icon. I'm currently running Mabox and a couple of ricing decisions I've taken have made my system tray nonfunctional for this sort of behaviour, is there any other way I could interact with this application? There seems to be no documentation available for proceeding with the installation on a purely CLI interace.

Comment: Could you try installating `stalonetray` (which is a standalone system tray) and, according to [this link](https://kolbusa.github.io/stalonetray/wmhints.html) would need to be run as `stalonetray -w` ; I've sadly never tried openbox so I can't assess whether it'll work great for your use case.

Comment: I must say that making it impossible to configure a hands-free input system by other means than *clicking in a tiny icon in a corner* is ... Not very clever.